# iOS: Pass data to modal VC when wrapped in a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, casting, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a VC that I'm presenting modally however that VC is wrapped in a `UINavigationController`. To present the Navigation Controller connected to my VC I added an identifier in storyboard and present like below:

```
if let nvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditTaskNavController") {
   self.present(nvc, animated: true){
      success(true)
   }          
 }
```

This presents fine. 
The problem arrises when I try to pass data to my VC. Because nvc is the navigation controller I tried to get the vc with `nvc.rootViewController` but I get the error: `Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'rootViewController'`. If I print out `nvc` I see that it is in fact a `UINavigationController`. I assume this error occurs because I used `instantiateViewController` to get the Navigation Controller from storyboard, but I'm confused why it prints out as a `UINavigationController`.

I've also tried to cast `nvc as? TaskEditViewController` but nvc is the navigation controller and not the vc so this doesn't work.

Ultimately I want to pass data to my VC as such before presenting modally:
 `vc.detail = "example"`

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast result of `instantiateViewController` to the appropriate type as the type of the vc you set the identifier to in storyboard as it returns a generic object of type `UIViewController` , so cast it to `UINavigationController`  , same case also is for property `topViewController`  that needs to be casted too

```
if let nvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditTaskNavController") as? UINavigationController, let top = nvc.topViewController as? TaskEditViewController {
    top.someProperty = /* some value */

    self.present(nvc, animated: true) {
        /* some code */
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the error `Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'topViewController'`